# How to show the value of $ x $-axis based on $ y $-axis and saved into table?

Tags: plotting, export, list-manipulation

I have a code here to calculate the value of y-axis of each partition based on `mx`. What I would like to do next is:

1. To show the value of each x-axis from the corresponding value of each `nMin` and `nMax` of y-axis generated.
2. Saved the result into 3 tables: only x-axis value, only y-axis value, and with both values.
3. Export each table into .xls format

The question is, how to do it? All help is greatly appreciated.

```
expr = (1/5)*Sqrt[-155900-100*Sqrt[1559]*Sqrt
[1/x]+Sqrt[24304810001+200*Sqrt[1559]*(1/x)^(3/2)*(50+155901*x)+(2500+31180100 x)/x^2]];

mx = 6;(*number of partition*)
nMin = NMinValue[{expr, 5 <= x <= 500}, x];
nMax = NMaxValue[{expr, 5 <= x <= 500}, x];
subRanges = Partition[Subdivide[nMin, nMax, mx], 2, 1]
Column[Plot[expr, {x, 5, 500}, PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, #}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, SuperStar[E]}, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  Reverse@subRanges]
```

This is the output value of `nMin` and `nMax` of y-axis for each partition where `mx=6` at y-axis:

> {{0.0636035, 0.158472}, {0.158472, 0.25334}, {0.25334, 
>         0.348208}, {0.348208, 0.443076}, {0.443076, 0.537944}, {0.537944, 
>         0.632812}}

Comment: What do you mean by {0.0636035, 0.158472} is the value of y-axis ??

Comment: @Lotus, I have edited the question for further clarification. Basically what im looking for is x-axis value for each `nMin` and `nMax` value of y-axis.

Comment: `yValues = Reverse@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@subRanges`, `xValues = NArgMin[{#, 5 <= x <= 500}, x] & /@  Abs[expr - Reverse@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@subRanges]`, `bothValues = Transpose[{xValues, yValues}]`.

Comment: @Alx Thank you Sir!